# How to make nested react routes v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am interested in 'how to make nested routes in my react project'.
It's hard to explain but this pictures below should ilustrated the problem:
[So this is common component with routes, nothing special](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaJdk.png)

[So this is the problem, because i want to have my routes in child component too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zaj30.png)

Is this a right way or maybe i have to put my child's routes in Parent component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all  you should include your code in the question and not as images.

Regarding your issue. This seems like a totally valid setup. What is clearly wrong is the `<BrowserRouter>` Element in your `Child` component. You should define only one router per App.

Comment: So i should remove BrowserRoute from Child?

Comment: One router is enough. You can setup as many Routes as you want in multiple places **if you need**. For code block please see that answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Can you send me an example?

Comment: If you can post your non-working example here or on jsfiddle (you can use the react fiddle as a base https://jsfiddle.net/Luktwrdm/), I will look into it